# Updated to Xcode5 simulator through get SIGABRT Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

An app I recently started and working its keeps crashing with a SIGABRT message. The general message at the top of the debugger says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0xb651580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key parentEmail.'
```

... At the the bottom it says:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Let me know if the "first throw call stack" info is necessary to solve this one.

Comment: Is you view (<UIView 0xb651580>) have parentEmail property ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure that you didnt previously have a button/text field/label previously linked with an action, then deleted that item. The link still exists. Check and make sure that all your links match to existing items.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this comes from an outlet link inside a xib with no corresponding class variable.
Did you remove a variable from a class without removing the link inside the xib?